# Infinispan 7.1 Cassandra cache-store

Tags: cassandra, infinispan

I have a very simple cache of type String, Long in Infinispan. I would like to persist this cache to cassandra.

I have installed Infinispan 7.1 Server and I have a cassandra instance running.

I've looked at http://infinispan.org/docs/cachestores/cassandra/ which lists two xml excerpts. Since I am completely new to Infinispan, I have no idea where to add the listed xml.

Is there an example Infinispan 7.1 server installation somewhere where this is setup and working?

**EDIT 1:**

I am able to use file based persistence by defining myCache as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:core:7.1" default-cache-container="clustered">
    <cache-container name="clustered" default-cache="default" statistics="true">
        <transport executor="infinispan-transport" lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <distributed-cache name="myCache" mode="SYNC" start="EAGER">
            <file-store
               shared="false" preload="true"
               fetch-state="true"
               read-only="false"
               purge="false"
               path="${java.io.tmpdir}">
              <write-behind flush-lock-timeout="15000" thread-pool-size="5" />
           </file-store>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

The schema for the xml defines a "store" element that extends "custom-store".

```
<xs:element name="store" type="tns:custom-store">
```

Sooo... I guess I need to study its schema to see how I can create a Cassandra store.

I have a constant feeling I'm doing something wrong because I can find no examples of anyone using this xml...

**EDIT 2**

Replaced file-store with the following:

```
<store 
    name="cassandraStore" 
    class="org.infinispan.loaders.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore"
    shared="true" preload="false" passivation="false"
    fetch-state="true">
    <property name="host">localhost</property>
    <property name="keySpace">mykeyspace</property>
    <property name="entryColumnFamily">mytable</property>
    <property name="expirationColumnFamily">mytableExpiration</property>
    <property name="sharedKeyspace">false</property>
    <property name="readConsistencyLevel">ONE</property>
    <property name="writeConsistencyLevel">ONE</property>
    <property name="configurationPropertiesFile">cassandrapool.properties</property>        
    <property name="keyMapper">org.infinispan.loaders.keymappers.DefaultTwoWayKey2StringMapper</property>
</store>
```

When I start infinispan server I get

> "JBAS010292: org.infinispan.loaders.cassandra.CassandraCacheStore is not a valid cache store"

Looking at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-cassandra I see the latest version is 6.0.0.Alpha1 from July of **2013**

I think the conclusion here is: **Cassandra is not supported by Infinispan.**

Comment: Currently, the cassandra cache store is owned by the community, so it's down to the Infinispan users to maintain it. We do this with a few of our cache stores to test their relevance. The more people get involved, the more we think it's being used and hence the more we are motivated towards fully supporting it. We'd gladly welcome your help to update the cache store to using Infinispan 7.1 parsers. That would be a great way to get involved :). We have plans to add Cassandra cache store to the main Infinispan repository but can provide guarantees at this point.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to mention this on this page: http://infinispan.org/cache-store-implementations/ since you are now falsely claiming to support a wide range of cache stores. This list specifically made me choose Infinispan. I cannot express the magnitude of my disappointment when the ugly truth was revealed. This has reflected poorly on both me and my company since we recommended Infinispan to a client _because_ it supports Cassandra.

Comment: There's nothing in that link that specifies what cache stores are supported versus which ones are not, so I don't believe we've made any false claims here. The list indicates the list of cache store implementations out there. Some are kept up to date more regularly than others though based on community needs/involvement. Thanks for recommending Infinispan and sorry to hear about your and your customer's disappointment.