# Infinispan 7.1 JDBC cache-store - dependencies missing

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, infinispan

I'm trying to setup a jdbc cache store in Infinispan 7.1 server. I previously tried to use the cassandra-cache-store but apparently it is no longer supported (see: [Infinispan 7.1 Cassandra cache-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797328/infinispan-7-1-cassandra-cache-store)).

There is a cassandra-jdbc driver (https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) available and it works just fine on its own. I am able to execute queries to cassandra successfully.

So I wanted to try and use this driver to setup a jdbc cache store on top of cassandra.

This is my configuration:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/mykeyspace</connection-url>
                <driver>org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver</driver>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:core:7.1">
        <cache-container name="clustered" default-cache="default" statistics="true">
            ...
            <distributed-cache name="myCounts" mode="SYNC" start="EAGER">
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store name="STRING_KEYED_JDBC_STORE" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" fetch-state="false" purge="false" read-only="false">
                    <string-keyed-table>
                        <id-column name="id" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="count" type="BIGINT"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

The cassandra-jdbc driver consists of 1 jar (cassandra-jdbc-2.1.1.jar) and 11 dependency jars. I've added these to standalone/lib/ext/ (no idea if this is the correct place since the documentation doesn't explain this).

I'm getting this error on startup:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "ExampleDS")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_apache_cassandra_cql_jdbc_CassandraDriver]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.org_apache_cassandra_cql_jdbc_CassandraDriver]"
]}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [these EAP instructions to install a JDBC driver as a core module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html) on top of Infinispan Server to install your Cassandra JDBC drivers since the base server works the same way.